# am getting identical sha256 for each json file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sha256

I am in a huge hashing crisis. Using the chip-0007's default format I generatedfew JSON files. Using these files I have been trying to generate sha256 hash value.  And I expect a unique hash value for each file.

However, python code isn't doing so. I thought there might be some issue with JSON file but, it is not. Something is to do with sha256 code.

**All the json files ->**

**JSON File 1**

```
{ "format": "CHIP-0007", "name": "adewale-the-amebo", "description": "Adewale always wants to be in everyone's business.", "attributes": [ { "trait_type": "Gender", "value": "male" } ], "collection": { "name": "adewale-the-amebo Collection", "id": "1" } }
```

**JSON File 2**

```
{ "format": "CHIP-0007", "name": "alli-the-queeny", "description": "Alli is an LGBT Stan.", "attributes": [ { "trait_type": "Gender", "value": "male" } ], "collection": { "name": "alli-the-queeny Collection", "id": "2" } }
```

**JSON File 3**

```
{ "format": "CHIP-0007", "name": "aminat-the-snnobish", "description": "Aminat never really wants to talk to anyone.", "attributes": [ { "trait_type": "Gender", "value": "female" } ], "collection": { "name": "aminat-the-snnobish Collection", "id": "3" } }
```

**Sample CSV File**:

```
Series Number,Filename,Description,Gender
1,adewale-the-amebo,Adewale always wants to be in everyone's business.,male
2,alli-the-queeny,Alli is an LGBT Stan.,male
3,aminat-the-snnobish,Aminat never really wants to talk to anyone.,female
```

---

**Python CODE**

## TODO 2 : Generate a JSON file per entry in team's sheet in CHIP-0007's default format

```
                new_jsonFile = f"{row[1]}.json"
                json_data = {}

                json_data["format"] = "CHIP-0007"
                json_data["name"] = row[1]
                json_data["description"] = row[2]

                attribute_data = {}
                attribute_data["trait_type"] = "Gender"  # gender
                attribute_data["value"] = row[3]  # "value/male/female"

                json_data["attributes"] = [attribute_data]

                collection_data = {}
                collection_data["name"] = f"{row[1]} Collection"
                collection_data["id"] = row[0]  # "ID of the NFT collection"

                json_data["collection"] = collection_data

                filepath = f"Json_Files/{new_jsonFile}"
                with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(json_data, f, indent=2)
                    C += 1
                    sha256_hash = sha256_gen(filepath)
                    temp.append(sha256_hash)

                    NEW.append(temp)


# TODO 3 : Calculate sha256 of the each entry
def sha256_gen(fn):
    return hashlib.sha256(open(fn, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
```

How can I generate a unique sha256 hash for each JSON?

I tried reading in byte blocks. That is also not working out. After many trials, I am going nowhere. Sharing the unexpected outputs of each JSON file:

[ All hashes are identical ]

**Unexpected SHA256 output:**

```
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

**Expected:**

Unique Hash value. Different from each other

Comment: I would be surprised if the hashlib library is so fundamentally broken that you can accidentally generate SHA256 collisions. It is virtually certain that you are feeding the same input to the hash function, even if you think you are not.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Are you sure `new_jsonFile` is changing each time?

Comment: Please post the code that loops over all the files.

Comment: @JohnColeman No each input is different

Comment: @Barmar yes, I have edited the question. Now, complete code along with sample csv and json files are in there

Comment: It looks like the indentation didn't copy correctly. Shouldn't the second `try` and call to `defaultJson()` be inside the `main()` function?

Comment: @Barmar yeah correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of output buffering, you're calling `sha256_gen(filepath)` before anything is written to the file, so you're getting the hash of an empty file. You should do that outside the `with`, so that the JSON file is closed and the buffer is flushed.

```
                with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(json_data, f, indent=2)
                C += 1
                sha256_hash = sha256_gen(filepath)
                temp.append(sha256_hash)

                NEW.append(temp)
```

Comment: Oh man! such a silly mistake I did. Thank you so much. I should have asked here 2 days ago. Yes, now it's working fine. Much love and blessings

Comment: Some simple debugging like printing `open(fn, 'rb').read()` might have clued you in to the problem.

Comment: My center of attraction was sha256 function. I thought mistake is there. In future tasks i'll keep this in mind.

Comment: for empty files sha256 doesn't change it's hash value? I ran multiple times and every time it was giving away the same result. Is it pre-defined?

Comment: The same input always gives the same hash.  Empty input is always the same.

Comment: Then this type of hashing is so predictable. Is there another approach to generate different sha256 hash each time for same input?

Comment: Hashing is supposed to be predictable. For instance, if you download a file and want to confirm that it wasn't modified, you hash the file and compare that with the hash published on the website. How would that work if your hash was different from when they posted the file?

Comment: If you're thinking of password hashing, that's made unpredictable by adding a random salt to the password before hashing it.